# How to put logic and assert dynamic data using karate

Tags: json, karate

Here is my one response for a particular request

```
{
    "data": {
        "foo": [{
            "total_value":200,
            "applied_value": [{
                "type": "A",
                "id": 79806,
                "value": 200
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Here is my another response for the **SAME** request

```
{
    "data": {
        "foo": [{
            "total_value":300,
            "applied_value": [{
                    "type": "A",
                    "id": 79806,
                    "value": 200
                },
                {
                    "type": "B",
                    "id": 79809,
                    "value": 100
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

I am unsure for which scenario will I get which response 
So the use case is 
Whenever there are 2 values in **applied_value** add two values and assert
Whenever there is only 1 value in **applied_value** directly assert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
* def adder = function(array) { var total = 0; for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) total += array[i]; return total }
* def response =
"""
{
    "data": {
        "foo": [{
            "total_value":300,
            "applied_value": [{
                    "type": "A",
                    "id": 79806,
                    "value": 200
                },
                {
                    "type": "B",
                    "id": 79809,
                    "value": 100
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
}
"""
* def expected = get[0] response..total_value
* def values = $response..value
* def total = adder(values)
* match expected == total
```

Just as an example, an alternate way to implement the `adder` routine is like this:

```
* def total = 0
* def add = function(x){ karate.set('total', karate.get('total') + x ) }
* eval karate.forEach(values, add)
```